# Is there a command to delete Webchat channel using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, web-chat

I am trying to delete webchat channel using Azure CLI but unable to find commands something similar to az bot webchat or az bot webchat show.

Please help me !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is not and no current way to remove with CLI. You might be able to use REST endpoints to delete the channel, or try calling the Azure botservice management SDK in a language of your choosing to delete the channel to do it programmatically. You can also use the GUI to remove the channel.

[image]

Comment: And even if you delete the Web Chat Channel, Azure will immediately create a new one in its place.  The best you can do is disable it -- and as Dana V pointed out, there is no CLI command to do it.